# Подскажите логику выполнения этой программы

Tags: java, swing, графика

Не могу понять как работает данный код?

```java
BufferedImage sr;//1
Graphics2D g2;//2
sr = new BufferedImage(576, 676, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);//3
g2 = sr.createGraphics();//4
g2.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);//5
mainLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(sr));//6
```

Я предполагаю, что это должно работать так:

1. объявляю объект типа BufferedImage
2. объявляю объект типа Graphics2D
3. создаю объект sr
4. создаю объект g2
5. рисую на объекте g2
6. вывожу на label картинку из sr

Получается, что я вывожу на Label картинку из sr. Но ведь я не рисовал на sr.(sr вообще не должна была измениться)
Я рисовал на g2. Почему же изменилась sr?
Не могу понять принцип. Подскажите логику выполнения этой программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Описание метода [BufferedImage.createGraphics из документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics())

> Creates a Graphics2D, which can be used to draw into this
> BufferedImage.

**Перевод:** Метод создает Graphics2D, который может быть использован для рисования на этом BufferedImage.

Грубо говоря, `Graphics2D` это контекст* рисования на данном графическом объекте, в данном случае это `BufferedImage`.

Так что ничего удивительного что используя контекст g2 вы рисуете на sr.

***** Контекст рисования - ни что иное, как объект-набор инструментов и функций для рисования на конечном устройстве (объекте отображения изображения).